# How to secure account balance in firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments, firebase-security

My first question here. I'd like to use Stripe as payment gateway in my ionic app. And update the balance in firebase after charging the user.

However, I'm not sure about how should I write the rule to secure the balance from re-writting by user. How should I write the rule?

My users stored as something like this

```
{
    users 
    {
        'nciwhjd7832hjkscdsd' {
            userName: 'Tom'
            balance: 20
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who/what will be writing the balance? Should the user be able to edit other fields? What API's are you using (for the user and updating the balance)? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I wouldn't allow this to happen on the client-side at all. Just lock down the rules so that `balance` is read-only and use [Stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to trigger a [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) which will update the balance on the server-side

Comment: @AndréKool Still trying to figure out what should I do, no code written for this. The process is like user A pay me to top up his account, then User A can give out the balance in his account to User B.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Good suggestion! Would like to try it yesterday but realise that the balance is not updated by stripe only. As the process is like user A pay me to top up his account, then User A can give out the balance in his account to User B. The amount among users are usually small. So, I can't use stripe for every inter-users payment. I have to, I think, allow the client-side to update the balance.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the firebase [rules][1] with writing your data as [transactions][2]

```
"users": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$uid": {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= 0",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
    }
}
```